# Discrete-time Fourier transform of $\frac{\cos(\frac{n\pi} 6)}{(n+3)\pi}$

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, homework, cosine, sinc

> Find the Discrete-time Fourier transform of $\frac{\cos(\frac{n\pi} 6)}{(n+3)\pi}$

I thought of making it to be a sinc, but at the bottom there is $n+3$ and **if I replace $n+3$** then I don’t know how to get rid of $-\pi/2$ in the new $\cos((\pi/6)m-0.5\pi)$

Could someone through me a hint?

Comment: But then how do I transform 1/cos(b)?

Comment: Infinity. n is index and result is periodic.

Comment: Continuous or discrete?  "n" implies discrete, "sinc" implies continuous.  (Your function is the normalized sinc in disguise.)

Comment: Discrete, sinc I meant - sampled.

Comment: Well, that clarifies nothing.  There are versions of the sinc function:  In the continuous domain, there is "sinc" and "normalized sinc".  In the discrete domain, there is "discrete sinc", aka "alias sinc" and "Dirichlet kernel".  Your function is a rescaled normalized sinc.  The DFT is defined on a finite interval.  So, if you are asking for the DFT of your function, the answer will depend on your interval definition.  Your function is not periodic.  The DFT of the continuous sinc is not going to be a "clean" answer.  In the continuous realm, sinc and rectangular functions are Fourier pairs.

Comment: @CedronDawg: The OP didn't mention the DFT. I suppose that the question is about the DTFT, and the DTFT of $\sin(n\omega_c)/(n\pi)$ is a well-known function.

Comment: @MattL. Thanks, OP doesn't say.  In that case, this should help:  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/48736/dtft-of-1n-cdot-mathrmsinc

Comment: Cease fire, I understood. I got cos() of something minus pi/2. It IS sinus of purely something. NOTE: that cos of pi is sinus of minus pi/2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{\cos(n\pi /6)}{(n+3)\pi}=\frac{\cos[(n+3)\pi/6 -\pi/2]}{(n+3)\pi}=\frac{\sin[(n+3)\pi/6]}{(n+3)\pi}$$

Comment: Clear. I still wonder why I commented

Comment: @LaurentDuval: Sometimes it's a good thing that comments can be deleted, isn't it? Unlike in real life ... :)

Comment: It's not deleted in my mind. Like in real life

Comment: 1)x[t-t0]=“something”*X(something else). 2)cos((n-3)pi-p/2)=sinus((n-3)pi).

Comment: My point of confusion was that I thought that the unit circle of e is the same unit circle of cos and sin. NOT TRUE! There are 3 different unit circles and they are not being described anywhere. This is something you and I need to understand. I’m willing to add this description to Wikipedia, let me know if it’ll help you. If not, I will do it later.

Comment: @VitaliPom Not sure what you are talking about about three different unit circles.  Nor does your last sentence make sense in the other comment.

$$ e^{i\theta} = \cos( \theta ) + i \sin( \theta ) $$

$$ \sin( \theta ) = \cos( \pi/2 - \theta ) = \cos( \theta - \pi/2 ) $$

These articles of mine may help you out:  https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/754.php and https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1238.php

Comment: Teta is (n -3)pi in the other comment, this exactly what I wrote. It's what being developed from the exercise and if you're refering to x[n-3] then it's just time shifting. All I'm looking is how to help to people with description in Wikipedia which will summarize the differences between e's circle, cos circle and sinus circle. Many people fall here down because sin & cos can be defined through the unit circle.

Comment: @VitaliPom Sine and cosine ARE defined by the unit circle.  The unit circle exists in the real plane (usually denoted with (x,y)) and the complex plane (usually denoted with (real, imaginary)), but the trig functions are identically defined in each.  There is a one-to-one mapping between the real and complex planes.  The location of a point on the unit circle (either one) can be found by how far along the circumference it is.  This distance is often denoted by $\theta$.  So Euler's equation is actually a conversion from the distance along the circumference to Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Ok, thanks Cedron :)!